# Why do `net.inet.ip.forwarding` and `net.inet.ip.fw.enable` kernel sysctl settings stay enabled even after disabling them on an Xserve running 10.6.8?

Tags: mac-osx-server, kernel, osx-snow-leopard, sysctl

Very bizarre situation. I have inherited a few Xservers from a previous admin that I have been charged with cleaning up on various levels. I am familiar with settings in Ubuntu and am very comfortable with the command line—including compiling from source—on top of knowing how to maneuver around the command line in OS X as well. But have come across something utterly baffling on one of the servers which is running 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

First oddity, I would like to turn the software firewall completely off. Sounds as simple as going into Server Admin and just telling it to stop the firewall right? Nope!  So if I turn off the firewall, and I do the following command to double check in the command line:

```
sysctl -a | grep net.inet.ip.fw.enable
```

The results are as expected:

```
net.inet.ip.fw.enable: 0
```

But then if I check it again within 5 minutes or so, it becomes magically enabled again:

```
net.inet.ip.fw.enable: 1
```

Ditto with NAT forwarding.

```
sysctl -a | grep net.inet.ip.forwarding
```

Disable it in the Server Admin, and this is the result:

```
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 0
```

A few minutes later:

```
net.inet.ip.forwarding: 1
```

WTF?!? I checked crontabs and I am the only user on the machine.

I do have the Server Admin app on another machine set to watch this machine, but it’s not running all of the time. And this issue did exist prior to that. I am not 10o% familiar with `sysctl` so need some guidance. FWIW, I do have some Ethernet tweaks I have set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` very recently, but no other commands or settings connected to the above.

Why would these settings seem to magically change after a few minutes? What can be done to stop that.

Thanks in advance for the help & pointers.

EDIT: Contents of `/etc/hostconfig` as per one of the comments below:

```
AFPSERVER=-NO-
AUTHSERVER=-NO-
TIMESYNC=-NO-
QTSSWEBADMIN=-NO-
QTSSRUNSERVER=-NO-
MYSQLCOM=-YES-
IPFORWARDING=-NO-
```

Comment: Was Gateway Setup Assistant run on this server at some point (possibly implied as that'll configure the Firewall, NAT, and DHCP services)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! No idea if Gateway Setup Assistant was run on the server. But being it is an “assistant” it would seem to me that whatever it did to configs can be rewound manually. But then again, no clue why it’s behaving that way.

Comment: what is the value of  IPFILTER in the /etc/hostconfig file, immediately after you turn off firewall and after it enables itself?

Comment: The only thing I've seen the firewall do automatically is re-open the port for serial number checks. You mentioned you've checked the crontabs, have you also checked `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`?

Comment: @Danielt. There is no entry for `IPFILTER` but there is an entry for `IPFORWARDING` and it is simply `NO`. I’ve posted the contents of the `/etc/hostconfig` in the main post for you to review. I don’t see anything significant.

Comment: You might need to manually set the `IPFILTER` flag. `IFPLITER=-NO-` . That is equivalent to `sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=0`. It won't hurt to try both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solved this one. Thanks for all of the advice folks!

What happened is there is a Java application running via a Mac shell program on this machine that has different options for creating a Jetty-based web interface. Somehow this was set to take over port 80—the standard HTTP port—and disabling that by changing the port URL to something else—like 666666—solved the issue.  `net.inet.ip.fw.enable` and `net.inet.ip.forwarding` stay set at `0` (aka: disabled) and don’t come back to life when the port is changed to a non-standard port for HTTP purposes.

That said, I still need to have content delivered via a standard port 80 connection. So I turned on web services on the server & set a reverse proxy from that to port 666666.  All behaves as it should.

But what is disturbing to me is how the application was able to takeover some `sudo` level functions—such as setting `sysctl` options—without seemingly ever asking for an admin password.  Is that normal for Jetty apps or idiosyncratic to this app? Maybe it asked for an admin password when it was installed before I even go to it? Do not know or care for now.  But clearing this up cleared up lots of networking issues on this box now that this application is no longer hijacking routing & firewall functions.

Comment: Performing root duties without having root would be a serious security issue, so it can be assumed that whatever your application is doing is doing it as root. Or it's not related to the problem at all, which seems more likely to me.

Comment: I can assure you that the problem is solved. Routing issues are now gone & networking behaves as expected for all services. The application acts as root for some other functions so the fact it has the capability to affect `sysctl` makes sense.  But it still makes no sense. Not naming the app, but we are exploring replacements.  And this maddening experience only adds fuel to the fire that it needs to be replaced or obsoleted ASAP.

Comment: Did you ever actually track the source? It might just be an impression, but from reading your post it seems to me like the exact cause of the problem was never found. I read it as "When this app starts it changes fw.enable and ip.forwarding but only when its port is used" which seems like awful behavior to me.

Comment: Yes, I tracked the source. It is this app.  Every 5 minutes `net.inet.ip.fw.enable` and `net.inet.ip.forwarding` would magically restart despite system settings when this application ran with port 80. Switching it to use a non-standard port such as 666666 results in `net.inet.ip.fw.enable` and `net.inet.ip.forwarding` staying disabled & never magically coming back.  I might do some disecting of the app itself to see if I can find the exact place where it sets this, but it is definitely this horrid application.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought but you could use the tool `auditctl` to see what processes are touching your `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

You can read more about auditctl over in this thread:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672039/see-what-process-last-touched-a-file

Specifically this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672155/33204

The gist is you run this command:

```
% sudo auditctl -p a -w /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And then watch the log file to see who's the guilty process:

```
% tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Comment: ??? My question has 100% nothing to do with `/etc/sysctl.conf`  That simply has a few Etherenet tweaks.  I’m the only person who has ever touched that file.  That does not address the issue of the firewall & NAT router deciding to come back to life on their own.

Comment: I was showing you an approach to detect changes to files. If you're confident something isn't touching /etc/sysct.conf then watch other files! I do not have a Mac but you could potentially watch the files under /proc or /sys if OSX has those exposed by the kernel similar to Linux.